# Muti-table inheritance and reverse relation django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-inheritance

I've been reading and practicing django 1.9 documentation about multi-table inheritance and reverse relation, this is my code:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Place(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField('Restaurant Name',max_length=50,db_column='name of restaurant')
    address=models.CharField('Restaurant Address',max_length=50,db_column='address of restaurant')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s and %s' % (self.name,self.address)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent_link=models.OneToOneField(Place,parent_link=True,default="",null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Suplier(Place):
    customers=models.ManyToManyField(Place,related_name='provider')
    suplier_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.suplier_name

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Consumer(Restaurant):
    myrestaurant=models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,null=True,related_name='restaurant_consumer')
    consumer_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.consumer_name
```

the relation `ManyToManyField` for Place (Parent Class) and Suplier (Child Class) works as expected (provide "related_name") but the problem is when i make another model inherit from another SubClass (Restaurant), when i want to make Consumer objects as follows:

```
>>> from multitableinheritance.models import Place,Restaurant,Suplier,Consumer
>>> Consumer.objects.all()
[]
>>> Consumer.objects.create(consumer_name='Andrew')
```

it is raise "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''". Full error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 735, in save_base
    self._save_parents(cls, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in _save_parents
    self._save_parents(cls=parent, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 760, in _save_parents
    self._save_table(cls=parent, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 801, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 831, in _do_update
    filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 790, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 808, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1243, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1269, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1203, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1099, in build_lookup
    return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 57, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 744, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 976, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

My question is, is it possible to make model relation inheritance from another SubClass / ChildClass, if it is possible is my code wrong. By the way the migrations for the models did not raise any error. Thank You for the answer and explanation, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The problem is some where else. Please post the full code and the full stacktrace

Comment: @e4c5 I have add my query code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After i try and modify my code finally i can make the Consumer Objects, this is the code that i have been modified (i add an id attribute in Place class since error happends in Autofield class ini `__init__.py` line 976)

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Place(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField('Restaurant Name',max_length=50,db_column='name of restaurant')
    address=models.CharField('Restaurant Address',max_length=50,db_column='address of restaurant')
    #---> add Place Class attribute id <---
    id=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1,primary_key=True,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s and %s' % (self.name,self.address)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent_link=models.OneToOneField(Place,parent_link=True,default="",null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Suplier(Place):
    customers=models.ManyToManyField(Place,related_name='provider')
    suplier_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.suplier_name

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Consumer(Restaurant):
    myrestaurant=models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,null=True,related_name='restaurant_consumer',default=1)
    consumer_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.consumer_name
```

Maybe someone can explain furthermore, the mechanism of id field in multi-table inheritance